# JavaFX 8 TreeView showing CheckBoxTreeItem with custom CheckBoxTreeCell - Checkbox Selection issue

Tags: java, checkbox, javafx, treeview, javafx-8

I have a strange checkbox selection issue with nodes that have Children in a JavaFX 8 TreeView using CheckBoxTreeItems with custom CheckBoxTreeCell.

The Problem is that checkboxes of Nodes with children have to be **clicked twice instead of once** in order to be selected. Leaves require only a single click.

My CheckBoxTreeItems take Person Objects. I override the updateItem() Method in my CheckBoxTreeCells to set the value displayed to the name of the Person in the TreeCell. If I don't call setText() in my overidden updateItem Method, the TreeCell displays the default toString() Method of my Person object (which is not what I want) and all nodes behave a expected when selecting their checkboxes.

I do not want to change the default toString in class Person, so the only workaround I see is to write a Wrapper class for Person that returns the Persons name in its toString(). But I prefer resolving this issue properly rather than using a workaround!

Any ideas? Help would be much appreciated!

Here is the code I use:

```
class Person {

  String name;

  int age;

  public Person(String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public int getAge() {
    return age;
  }

  public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
  }
}
```

and

```
public class TreeUtilTest extends Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
   VBox vBox = new VBox();

   TreeView<Person> treeView = new TreeView<>();
   treeView.setCellFactory(p -> new CheckBoxTreeCell<Person>() {

     @Override
     public void updateItem(Person item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (item != null) {
           setText(item.getName());
        }
     }
    });
   vBox.getChildren().add(treeView);

   CheckBoxTreeItem<Person> treeRoot = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>();
   treeRoot.setValue(new Person("Peter", 10));
   treeRoot.setIndependent(true);
   treeView.setRoot(treeRoot);

   IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(i -> {
      CheckBoxTreeItem<Person> item = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>();
      item.setValue(new Person("Friend", i));
      item.setIndependent(true);
      treeRoot.getChildren().add(item);
   });


   Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
   primaryStage.setScene(scene);
   primaryStage.show();
}

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at `CheckBoxTreeCell` [class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxTreeCell.html#CheckBoxTreeCell-javafx.util.Callback-javafx.util.StringConverter-), you'll see it has the possibity to provide a callback that returns an `ObservableValue<Boolean>` with the selection status of the item, and a `StringConverter`.

So we can define these in our class:

```
final Callback<TreeItem<Person>, ObservableValue<Boolean>> getSelectedProperty =
        (TreeItem<Person> item) -> {
    if (item instanceof CheckBoxTreeItem<?>) {
        return ((CheckBoxTreeItem<?>)item).selectedProperty();
    }
    return null;
}; 
final StringConverter<TreeItem<Person>> converter = 
        new StringConverter<TreeItem<Person>>() {

    @Override
    public String toString(TreeItem<Person> object) {
        Person item=object.getValue();
        return item.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public TreeItem<Person> fromString(String string) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
};
```

And now we just need to define the cell factory with these two parameters:

```
treeView.setCellFactory(p -> new CheckBoxTreeCell<>(getSelectedProperty,converter));
```

If you try this, you will see that you can select/unselect the root as well as the children with just one click.

**EDIT**

There's an easier solution, using the static method `forTreeView`, where you don't need to provide the callback nor the converter:

```
treeView.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeCell.<Person>forTreeView());
```

But for this to work you just need to override `toString` in `Person`:

```
private class Person {
    ...
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

  }
```

And this explains why you had the problem in the first place: if you add the `toString` method to your code, it will work also with your `CheckBoxTreeCell`:

```
treeView.setCellFactory(p -> new CheckBoxTreeCell<Person>() {

 @Override
 public void updateItem(Person item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (item != null) {
       setText(item.getName());
    }
 }
});
```

Comment: Isn't  the callback supposed to fire when a checkboxitem is Selected? or is there some other way ?

Comment: The callback is the way to provide the binding bewteen the treeItem and the checkBox, while the stringConverter just provides how to format the label. In fact, you're right, there's an easier solution. Please have a look to the Edit section in my previous answer.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution, but that won't be possible in my case. In the real-life version I don't have access to the sources of the business objects. I could write a wrapper for "Person" and override the toString() as you suggested, but thats not the solution I was hoping for. As for the callback: in my case it never gets called when I check a checkbox in the tree ... Any ideas?

Comment: But all the checkboxes are properly selected/unselected, right? As you must provide the string converter, you need to provide the callback too, even it's not necessary in this case. You'll notice the callback gets called when you have `TreeItem` instances different than `CheckBoxTreeItem`, so you can return a proper select property for them if you need to.

Comment: Thank you. You helped me a lot!